# DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm quite a newbie to node.js and I'm currently using discord.js to make a Discord bot. As soon as any bot command gets used the console prints a DeprecationWarning.
for example:

```
(node:15656) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
```

`(node:15656)` sometimes is another number, nearly always changing.
This is what my code looks like (only one command, I've got multiple, I get this error with all of them though):

```
const botconfig = require("./botconfig.json")
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on("ready", () => { 
    console.log(`Launched ${bot.user.username}...`);
    bot.user.setActivity("Games", { type: "PLAYING" });
});

bot.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    let prefix = botconfig.prefix;
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let cmd = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);
    let botico = bot.user.displayAvatarURL;

    if (cmd == `${prefix}help`) {
        let helpEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .addField(".kick", "kick a user", true)
            .addField(".ban", "ban a user", true)
            .addField(".unban", "unbans a user", true)
            .addField(".mute", "mutes a user over a period of time", true)
            .setColor("#005b5f")
            .setThumbnail(botico);

        message.channel.send(helpEmbed);
        console.log(`command used: help`);
    };
});

bot.login(botconfig.token)
```

Comment: Usually, it's a good idea not to post the whole code, since it may be irrelevant, but in this case it's better to post it all: Somewhere in your code you called `.find()` but in this part of the code it doesn't appear anywhere. Try searching for a `.find()` in your code and then post that part ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is in one of your other commands. You more than likely are using something like `#Collection.find('name', 'keyname')` in one of the other commands.

This has been updated to `#Collection.find(x => x.name === "name")`.

Like it says in the error. #Collection.find() requires a function instead. So use one and the error goes away.