# How can I make it so that my bot gives a role to a user when they repeat a set of numbers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot that gives a user a role for full access to a Discord server.

I have made the bot provide a random number and give a user a guest role when they join, but I need my bot to give them a member role when they repeat the number.

Here is my code:

```
let code;

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => { 
    const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'captcha');
    if (!channel) return;

        member.addRole(member.guild.roles.find("name", "Guest"));

        code = Math.floor(Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() * 992875 + Math.random());

        channel.send('Welcome, ' + member.toString() + '! Please repeat these numbers to get access to this server: ' + code);

     if (message.content == code) {

        member.addRole(member.guild.roles.find("name", "Member"));

        code = -1;

    }
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content === 'fakeJoin--') {
        client.emit('guildMemberAdd', message.member || await message.guild.fetchMember(message.author));
    }
});
```

I don't get any error message, the bot doesn't crash. Nothing happens when I repeat the number.

Comment: did you try to solve the problem yourself? Like using log. For example, you can add a `console.log(message.content, code)` before the if, and a `console.log('yes')` in the if to see if the program enter there. By doing this step by step, you'll maybe solve your problem, and if you don't succeed, you'll have better information to give to people to help you

Comment: If the purpose of this system is to prevent harmful bots under user accounts, it can easily be bypassed if you know what the message looks like (take the message, extract the code, reply with it). There's npm packages to help generate a real CAPTCHA within an image which is much more secure and native-looking.

Answer (score 0):

After sending the message with the code, your client can't magically know what the response is. However, your code seems to assume that; you're trying to read `message.content` when there is no message in a [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event.

To solve this issue, you need to capture the messages sent in the channel, then read the user's response.

---

**Option A:** Message Collector

A [MessageCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector) can be created to (you guessed it!) collect messages sent in a channel. In your case, you can create one, check the message upon collection, and compare the content to the correct code.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
  if (member.user.bot) return;

  const channel = member.guild.channels.find(c => c.type === 'text' && c.name === 'captcha');

  const guestRole = member.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Guest');
  const memebrRole = member.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Member');

  try {
    await member.addRole(guestRole);

    let code = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) code += `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}`;

    await channel.send(`Welcome, ${member}. Please repeat this code to continue: \`${code}\``);

    const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(message => message.author.id === member.id, { maxMatches: 1 });
    collector.on('collect', async message => {
      if (message.content === code) {
        await channel.send('Thank you. You may now continue into the server.');

        await member.removeRole(guestRole);
        await member.addRole(memberRole);
      } else await member.kick('Failed verification.');
    });
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

**Option B:** Awaiting Messages

[`TextChannel.awaitMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) is the asynchronous equivalent of a message collector. However, the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) always resolves with a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection).

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
  if (member.user.bot) return;

  const channel = member.guild.channels.find(c => c.type === 'text' && c.name === 'captcha');

  const guestRole = member.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Guest');
  const memebrRole = member.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Member');

  try {
    await member.addRole(guestRole);

    let code = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) code += `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}`;

    await channel.send(`Welcome, ${member}. Please repeat this code to continue: \`${code}\``);

    const collected = await channel.awaitMessages(message => message.author.id === member.id, { maxMatches: 1 });
    const message = collected.first(); // The only message in the returned Collection.
    if (message.content === code) {
      await channel.send('Thank you. You may now continue into the server.');

      await member.removeRole(guestRole);
      await member.addRole(memberRole);
    } else await member.kick('Failed verification.');
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

---

You'll notice a few changes in the base code that I made. I'd like to explain some of these improvements.

- The event callback must be defined as async to use the keyword [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) inside of it.
- If the new user is a bot, they won't have to go through verification. They wouldn't be able to complete it anyway, and you must have the `MANAGE_SERVER` permission to add it in the first place.
- See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026292/deprecationwarning-collectionfind-pass-a-function-instead) regarding the deprecated usage of [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find).
- When dealing with Promises, you should always make sure to handle any rejections, hence the [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement.
- The code generation will result in a string of 6 random integers. Other random number generation methods are not as random or inclusive.
- When the user passes verification, a new message will be sent and they'll also be removed from the Guest role (assuming it's temporary).
- When the user fails verification, they'll be kicked.